# Mail with html content shows break lines or ignores newlines

Tags: email, templates, go, mandrill

I am sending mail to users via mandrill and I using both smtp and mandrill api to send.
Content of the mail is rendered go template (`.tpl`)
When I put template like

```
Hi {{.name}},
<br/>
This is support.  
<br/>
```

it sends via mandrill api ok, but 
 is visible when I send via smtp, 
when use template like ( `<br/> replaced with \n`)

```
Hi {{.name}},

This is support.
```

mandrill ignores that and shows everything in one line but smtp shows ok newlines.
What is a solution for this ?

I am rendering template like

```
frame, err := template.New("foo").Parse( *templateString )
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
var doc bytes.Buffer
frame.Execute( &doc, *parameters )
temp := doc.String()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sending the mail as HTML? If so, you can wrap everything in the `<pre>` tag.

If you're not using HTML, setting this header should help: `Mime-Type: text/plain`

Also, try changing your newlines from `\n` to `\r\n`.